# logging when there is more than one server

Tags: php, gearman

I currently use text files to track errors or watch process in the system.
I thinking to scale with Gearman and to have workers on separated machines.
What is the way to logging when you have multiple servers , assuming I'm want to keep logging into text files and to have overall view of the process.

Comment: I would log to a database (anyway) ... so one central logging database/server is not the worst solution, if you plan to monitor several servers.

Answer (score 0):

We use syslog-ng for apache and php error logs - it can collect different logs with different filters and send it to the central storage.